# How to Show File Path with Browse Button in Python / Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Working with Python and Tkinter, I have been trying to find out the way to show the file_path beside the Browse Button but unable to do so.

Here is my code:

```
  import os
  from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
  from Tkinter import *


  content = ''
  file_path = ''


  #~~~~ FUNCTIONS~~~~

  def open_file():
    global content
    global file_path

    filename = askopenfilename()
    infile = open(filename, 'r')
    content = infile.read()
    file_path = os.path.dirname(filename)
    return content

  def process_file(content):
    print content

  #~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


  #~~~~~~ GUI ~~~~~~~~

  root = Tk()
  root.title('Urdu Mehfil Ginti Converter')
  root.geometry("598x120+250+100")

  mf = Frame(root)
  mf.pack()


  f1 = Frame(mf, width=600, height=250)
  f1.pack(fill=X)
  f2 = Frame(mf, width=600, height=250)
  f2.pack()

  file_path = StringVar


  Label(f1,text="Select Your File (Only txt files)").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='e')
  Entry(f1, width=50, textvariable=file_path).grid(row=0,column=1,padx=2,pady=2,sticky='we',columnspan=25)
  Button(f1, text="Browse", command=open_file).grid(row=0, column=27, sticky='ew', padx=8, pady=4)
  Button(f2, text="Process Now", width=32, command=lambda: process_file(content)).grid(sticky='ew', padx=10, pady=10)


  root.mainloop()


  #~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Kindly guide me as how I can show the file path along with the "Browse Button" button after the user selects the file as shown in this [image](http://i225.photobucket.com/albums/dd190/ahm4me/Tkinter_AskOpen1_zpsedb9d45c.jpg).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, change this line:

```
    Entry(f1, width=50, textvariable=file_path).grid(row=0,column=1,padx=2,pady=2,sticky='we',columnspan=25)
```

to this:

```
entry = Entry(f1, width=50, textvariable=file_path)
entry.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=2,pady=2,sticky='we',columnspan=25)
```

Then, in the `open_file()` function, add these two lines, just before the `return`:

```
entry.delete(0, END)
entry.insert(0, file_path)
```

---

**Explanation**:
First, we give the entry a name, so that it can be modified.
Then, in the `open_file()` function we clear it and add the text for the file-path.

Comment: Thank you very much @laurencevs! I spend hours to get this functional but I was unable. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @pleasureinblues You can show others that this answer was useful by clicking on the little tick on its left.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a diff that fixes instead the `file_path`, i.e. the `StringVar()` usage:

```
--- old.py      2016-08-10 18:22:16.203016340 +0200
+++ new.py      2016-08-10 18:24:59.115328029 +0200
@@ -4,7 +4,6 @@


 content = ''
-file_path = ''


 #~~~~ FUNCTIONS~~~~
@@ -16,7 +15,7 @@
   filename = askopenfilename()
   infile = open(filename, 'r')
   content = infile.read()
-  file_path = os.path.dirname(filename)
+  file_path.set(os.path.dirname(filename))
   return content

 def process_file(content):
@@ -40,7 +39,7 @@
 f2 = Frame(mf, width=600, height=250)
 f2.pack()

-file_path = StringVar
+file_path = StringVar(root)


 Label(f1,text="Select Your File (Only txt files)").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='e')
```